# Complicated expression for Calculate Field for arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-parser, expression, error-999999

I have a working formula that I can put in the Field Calculator which I'd like to use in my python code:

> .3-.001*Log ( [Field1]+1  )-.02*Log ( [Field2]+1 )-.04*Log (
>   [Field3]+1 )

My code:

```
import math
expression =".3-.001*Log(!Field1!+1)-.02*Log(!Field2!+1)-.04*Log(!Field3!+1)"
arcpy.CalculateField_management("Layer","Field4",expression)
```

> ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Syntax error
>   Failed to execute (CalculateField).

How can I write this expression?

Comment: `expression =".3-.001*math.log(!Field1!+1)-.02*math.log(!Field2!+1)-.04*math.log(!Field3!+1)"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change "Log" to "math.log" .

If you want to use your code in  Field Calculator, just use formula in it:

> 0.3-.001*math.log(!Field1!+1)-0.02*math.log(!Field2!+1)-0.04*math.log(!Field3!+1)

**In Python IDE:**

You need to assign "PYTHON_9.3" to the last parameter of the "arcpy.CalculateField_management".

Don't forget **import arcpy** in the beginning of the code when you use the code in the Python IDE or console.

```
 import arcpy,math
 expression = '.3-.001*math.log(!Field1!+1)-.02*math.log(!Field2!+1)-.04*math.log(!Field3!+1)'
 arcpy.CalculateField_management("Layer","Field4",expression,"PYTHON_9.3")
```

Comment: ive always wondered why you need import arcpy for field calculator... its inside arcmap you would think its imported by default (like the arcmap python terminal?)

Comment: I supposed you use this code in the python IDE. OK i edited my answer. If you use this code in the field calculator you'll not need to use import arcpy

Comment: @Geo.Dude, @wetland If you're using this code in the field calculator you wouldn't be calling `arcpy.CalculateField_management()`

Comment: @Midavalo  You'r right. I edited the answer. Thanks.